# Firefox tab behavior - open at end of list, rather than next to spawning tab?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, opera, browser-tabs

If you are on a page in Firefox and open a link in a new tab (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-Click on Windows/Linux, <kbd>⌘</kbd>-click on a Mac), it opens in sequence next to the tab you are launching from.

Is it possible to make all "open in new tab" actions open at the end of the tab bar, like in Opera or Chrome?

Comment: I can't say I've seen a keyboard that had a `Crtl` key before. `Ctrl`, certainly, but never `Crtl`.

Comment: @Hello71 ... *obviously* you do not have the dyslexics keyboard **I** do :) .. thanks for the spot :)

Comment: As far as I know, Chrome doesn't have that, to begin with.

Comment: @Eugene - Chrome doesn't have which?

Comment: @warren doesn't have native support for option to open new tab at the end.

Comment: @Eugene - it used to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Firefox type `about:config` in the address bar and hit enter. Click past the warning message.

In the filter field type "insertRelated".

Double click the resulting **browser.tabs.insertRelatedAfterCurrent** line to toggle it to False.

Comment: Note: no add-in install necessary :-)

Comment: awesome - I was guessing somewhere in `about:config` but had no idea where :)

Answer (score 3):

[Tab Mix Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1122/) addon can help you do this. Just navigate to `Tab Mix Plus Options` and under `Events > Tab Opening` tab, and clear the checkboxes near

- `Open new tabs next to current one`

and

- `Open other tabs next to current one`.