# Firefox 13+, how to load new tab thumbnails from current tab?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs, thumbnails

Sometimes I end up with 20+ tabs, and if I'm on tab number 2 and I finish my business with that tab, to open a new tab with thumbnails I have to hit CMD-T, but that opens the new tab at the far end. Is there a way I can get the new tab thumbnails from my current tab?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Tab Mix Plus addon mentioned here might help you out: http://superuser.com/a/184369/8807